# ArrayList remove doesn't work?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

This is part of my code.

```
private static List<Client> clients = null;

public static boolean disconnectClient(Socket client)
{
    try{
        System.out.println("[SYSTEM] : " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + "was disconnected !!");
        clients.remove(client);

        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

if client disconnected call this function and print message

```
console : "[SYSTEM] : 127.0.0.1was disconnected !!"
```

but clients.size(); is return 1 (0 is answer...)

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Your `clients` List is made of `Client` objects but when you remove, a `Socket` object is being used and hence the original list is unaltered.

Comment: Oh...!! My best Mistake LOL

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a socket object to remove ().
But your list is consisted from Client objects.
You should pass a client object instead.